# How to Compile Code of windows Phone Using MsBuild . 

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone

How to Compile Code of Windows phone 7 Using MsBuild ? MsBild Window Comes and Dissappears suddenly .

Comment: It is possible: try code the program in hexadecimal codes directly in machine code. :) = only for fun :) :)

Comment: [Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/windows-phone-developer-tools) is free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible, but it would cost so much unnecessary time and it's quite hard for someone who doesn't know what they are doing (no offence).

But why wouldn't you use the IDE?
You can just download Visual Studio 2010 (and later 2012) Express and start developing for Windows Phone! Just check out http://create.msdn.com/

Keep in mind though, that if you want to put your apps in the marketplace it will cost you 100 dollar a year.